# Confusion on Javascript regex with match function

Tags: javascript, regex

Why is the third element in the array just '.1' rather than '4.5.1'? I thought that the `\d+` would correspond to '3' and the `(\.\d)*` would capture the remaining decimals and numbers.

```js
var re = /see (chapter \d+(\.\d)*)/i;
var str = 'For more information on regular expressions, see Chapter 3.4.5.1 and CHAPTER 2.3';
    
console.log(str.match(re));
```

Output:

```
[ 'see Chapter 3.4.5.1',
  'Chapter 3.4.5.1',
  '.1',
  index: 45,
  input: 'For more information on regular expressions, see Chapter 3.4.5.1 and CHAPTER 2.3' ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A repeated capturing group will only capture its *last* repetition. If you wanted to capture *all* of the numbers and periods, you should repeat *inside* the group:

```js
var re = /see (chapter \d+((?:\.\d)*))/i;
var str = 'For more information on regular expressions, see Chapter 3.4.5.1 and CHAPTER 2.3';
    
console.log(str.match(re));
```

If you plug in your original code into regex101, you'll see a warning describing this:

https://regex101.com/r/uDTcTC/1

> A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data

Answer (score 0):

```
array[0] is a full match
array[1] is a group match caused by a wider parenthesis (chapter \d+(\.\d)*)
array[2] is a group match caused by the narrow parenthesis  (\.\d)*
```